# Updating variables and killing threads during thread execution

Tags: c++, multithreading, raspberry-pi, pthreads, c++17

I am working on a raspberry pi project and want to have a parallel thread in my application that blinks an LED with different frequencies for different states of the application. I think this should be done by threads...

Basically I have an enum and couple of structs to define the states, the GPIO pins and the appropriate action when a status is required. Each status will blink a LED for a given number of times with predefined ON and OFF times.

Then there is a thread that keeps track of a global variable for current state.

My problem is, the function that performs the GPIO state change and On/OFF times using "sleep", sometimes need to be abruptly stopped and a new state be initiated.

How to approach this problem? Below is my very simplified version of code.

```
enum class Status { // Possible states of the application
    Ok = 0,
    ErrorNetwork,
    NetworkOk
    /* and more status! */
};

struct StatusPin { // Define a pin
    std::string name;
    const int number; // Pin number
};

// Define a pin and its action
struct StatusAction {
    std::string name;
    const StatusPin pin;
    const unsigned int cycles;
    const unsigned int millisOn;
    const unsigned int millisOff;
};

// Create one pin
const StatusPin G_StatusLed = { 
    "Status LED", 
    2
};

// Map for status states
std::map<const Status, StatusAction> G_StatusMap = {
        // One short blink
        {Status::Ok, 
                {"Running", G_StatusLed, 1, 250, 0}},

        // Blink 3 times with 500ms delay
        {Status::ErrorNetwork,
                { "Network Error", G_StatusLed, 3, 500, 500}},

        // Blink 6 times, 1 second high, 500ms low
        {Status::NetworkOk,
                { "Network OK", G_StatusLed, 6, 1000, 500}}                

        /* and more states! */
}

const void performStatusAction(const StatusAction &action) {    
    for (int i = 0; i < action.cycles; i++) {
        pi::digitalWrite(action.pin.number, 1); // Set high
        
        // Sleep for high duration
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(
                std::chrono::milliseconds(action.millisOn));
        pi::digitalWrite(action.pin.number, 0); // Set LOW

        // Sleep for low duration
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(
                std::chrono::milliseconds(action.millisOff));
    }    
}
    
//------ GLOBAL VARIABLES ------\\
std::mutex mutex;
App::StatusAction* G_CurrentAction = nullptr; // Variable for status action
std::atomic<bool> G_AppRunning {true};
std::atomic<bool> G_StatusWorkerBusy {false};
    
//------- THREAD FUNCTION  -------\\
void statusWorker() {
    while(G_AppRunning) {
        mutex.lock();
        G_StatusWorkerBusy = true;
        if(G_CurrentAction && !G_CurrentAction->name.empty()) {

            performStatusAction(*G_CurrentAction);

            // If OneShot, set point to null so that it does not repeat
            if(G_CurrentAction->type == App::StatusActionType::OneShot) {
                G_CurrentAction = nullptr;
            } else {
                spdlog::warn("StatusWorker NULLPTR");
            }
        }
        G_StatusWorkerBusy = false;
        mutex.unlock();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);
    }
}  
    
int main() {
    init(); // Setup GPIO mode, etc...

    std::thread threadStatus(statusWorker); // Start status thead

    // Update thread variable and set
    G_CurrentAction= &G_StatusMap.at(Status::Ok);


    bool isAppDone = false;
    
    // Main loop
    while(!isAppDone) {

        // do something long e.g. Check for network failed
        // Set status to network error
        G_CurrentAction= &G_StatusMap.at(Status::ErrorNetwork);
        
        // Immidieatly after 1 second network is back, set new status
        // Pervious status should stop and new status should be set
        // How to cancel loop inside the statusWorker performStatusAction() ?
        G_CurrentAction= &G_StatusMap.at(Status::NetworkOk);

        /*
            Do good stuff here and update status thread if necessary
        */


        // At some point exit the loop
        isAppDone = true;
    }


    // Clear up stuff
    threadStatus.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: “I think this should be done by threads...” → you might want to question that.

Comment: Instead of `sleep`, you could use e.g. a timed wait on a condition variable, `std::condition_variable::wait_for`. This way the sleep can be interrupted by notifying the condition variable.

Comment: Threads are overkill here - you're polling the GPIO every 1ms. You can do all other stuff in the same loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, we want the LED status thread to notice anytime the app's gross state changes, so the thread can change its flashing/occulting pattern accordingly.

To do this, we can have a `std::condition_variable` representing the predicate "the state changed."  Then, inside the status thread's loop, anytime we're idle we `wait_for` a signal on that condition variable (instead of `sleep_for` some time).  If state has changed, we'll start over with a new pattern of flashing.

It'd look something like this:

```
std::condition_variable status_cv;
std::mutex m;

....

// inside status thread
while (G_AppRunning) {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locked(m);

  // what is app state when we enter this pass?
  Status status = G_CurrentStatus;
  ActionStatus action = G_StatusMap.at(status);

  for (int i = 0; i < action.cycles; i++) {
    LED_on();
    if (status_cv.wait_for(locked, action.millisOn, [] { return G_CurrentStatus != status; })) {
      break; // start anew with a status pattern
    }

    LED_off();
    if (status_cv.wait_for(locked, action.millisOff, [] { return G_CurrentStatus != status; })) {
      break; // new state
    }
  }
}
```